# Changing root in XML for xml.etree

Tags: python, xml

I have a file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"etc>
<xliff version="1.2"  etc>
<file datatype="plaintext" mt="eMT-R2" original="" source-language="en-US" target-language="es">
<header/>
<body>
    <trans-unit etc>
        <source>blabla</source>
        <target>blabla</target>
        <note>blabla</note>
    </trans-unit>
</body>
</file>
</xliff>
```

I want to go through the source and target elements. My code only works if I have `<body>` as a root. Is there a way to skip the first 4 elements at the beginning of the file or just set the root to `<body>`?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('myfile.xlf')
root = tree.getroot()

for trans in root.findall('trans-unit'):
    source = trans.find('source').text
    target = trans.find('target').text
    lencomp = (len(target) - len(source))/len(source)*100.0
    print(source,">>>", target)
```

Comment: On the subject of question writing... posting valid xml means we can test without having to fix it ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

ElementTree's `findall` takes a quasi-xpath string. Its not a full-featured xpath like is available with `lxml` but works for what you need

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('myfile.xlf')

for trans in tree.findall('file/body/trans-unit'):
    source = trans.find('source').text
    target = trans.find('target').text
    lencomp = (len(target) - len(source))/len(source)*100.0
    print(source,">>>", target)
```

Comment: I get the following with tree.xpath: AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'xpath'

Comment: My bad, I was thinking `lxml` not `xml.etree`. I've updated to use xpath in `findall`.

Comment: Thanks @tdelaney - I found the problem and posted the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it turns out the problem is not in the code but in my file. For anyone working with XLIFF files, this may be useful:

The issue is in the "[XMLNS](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp)" - if you remove at least one letter, the file will be parsed correctly. I'm not sure exactly what the problem is, but changing this definitely solves the problem